Shopware 6 - how to call ADMIN API from my backend application route
I am building the Shopware 6 application. I use SYMFONY on ma backend together with Shopware SYMFONY bundle. I have in my manifest.xml section below:
    <admin>
        <!-- change the source url param on production -->
        <module name="main"
                source="http://shopware-app-backend.docker:8080/"
                parent="sw-catalogue"
                position="50"
        >
            <label>My module</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">My module</label>
        </module>
    </admin>

Then in my app backend I have Controller which is like below:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Administration\UserInterface\Controller;

use Shopware\App\SDK\Context\Module\ModuleAction;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

#[Route('/{reactRouting}', name: 'app_default', requirements: ['reactRouting' => '^(?!app|api).+'], defaults: ['reactRouting' => null])]
final class AppController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(ModuleAction $module, Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->render('administration/index.html.twig');
    }
}

The index.html.twig loads the react application on the frontend.
The frontend app calls my backend app API. For example
const response = await axios.get("api/products");

The question is how to authenticate requestes from my frontend to my backend app where my backend sometimes needs to talk to the Shopware ADMIN API. For example in my backend app controller I have route like this:
    #[Route('/api/products', name: 'app_api_products')]
    public function apiProducts( ): Response
    {

        // HOW TO AUTHENTICATE THIS REQUEST SO I COULD TALK TO SHOPWARE API
        
        // HERE I WANT TO DOWNLOAD PRODUCTS LIST FROM SHOPWARE ADMIN API AND MAKE SOME REQUESTS TO MY APPLICATION DATABASE AND MANIPULATE SOME DATA

      
        return new JsonResponse();
    }

I know that I may use access and refresh token, but I need username and password which is not available in my backend app.
Antoher option is Integration (Client Credentials Grant Type) which resturns access token, however it doesn't provide refresh token so after 10 minutes it's expired so I am not able to refresh it.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you
I have no idea how to achievie it.
